# Linha vertical no meio da tela do Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Como eu faço pra remover essa linha que fica bem no meio da tela de codificação do Visual Studio Code?

[image: Imagem da linha que aparece]

Comment: Essa linha é boa para manter um ponto "desejado" de tamanho máximo da linha. Em diversos lugares se tem um limite/melhor visualização de 80 caracteres.

Answer (score 2):

Vai em Preferences -> Text Editor -> Markers and Rulers e desmarque a opção Show Column Ruler.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49127327/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, eu resolvi seguindo o seguinte passo:

CTRL + SHIFT + P --> Open settings --> remove a propriedade rulers

Answer (score -5):

"editor.rulers": [80,120],